# How to stop NHibernate from logging in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I created an Azure web job project that uses Fluent NHibernate for its ORM. The program itself works fine and does what it's supposed to. However, after publishing the web job and running it live, **every single SQL statement that NHibernate generates** is output to the log, and I don't want this.

I thought that NHibernate by default does not output SQL statements, and I would have to enable it explicitly. However, it seems to be happening automatically, and I can't seem to turn it off. Is there some setting somewhere that I need to set to stop this logging?

This is my configuration, my app.config, and an example database query:

**NHibernate configuration**

```
    public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        string connString = ConnectionStringHelper.ConnectionString;
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                .ConnectionString(connString)
            )
            .Cache(c => c
                .UseQueryCache())
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Functions>())
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

**App config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***;AccountKey=***" />
    <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***;AccountKey=***" />
  </connectionStrings>
    <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.7.0.0" newVersion="5.7.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Sample DB Query**

```
            using (ISessionFactory sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory())
            {
                using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
                {
                    var accountCrit = session.CreateCriteria<AccountRec>();
                    accountCrit.Add(Expression.Eq("AccountId", batch.AccountId));
                    var accounts = accountCrit.List<AccountRec>();
                }
            }
```

The above statement generates this in the Azure logs:

```
[09/06/2017 03:57:30 > 442002: INFO] NHibernate: SELECT this_.AccountId as AccountId9418_0_, this_.RingCentralId as RingCent2_9418_0_, this_.RingCentralExtension as RingCent3_9418_0_ FROM T_ACCOUNT this_ WHERE this_.AccountId = @p0;@p0 = '253' [Type: Int]
```

But I don't want it to generate that in the logs.

Comment: Are you using the default Log4Net logging that NHibernate has?

Comment: I am not. In fact, I do not even have a reference to Log4Net in my project anywhere.

Comment: I can't repro the issue that you mentioned on my side with you supplied code. I assume it is not related to azure platform, it seems casued by NHibernate. Do you have a try to configurate Diagnostics disable? Fluently.Configure() .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008 .ConnectionString(connString) ) .Cache(c => c .UseQueryCache()) .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Functions>()) .Diagnostics(x=>x.Disable()) .BuildSessionFactory();

Comment: Nice thought, @Tom, but I tried it and it didn't seem to make a difference. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that somehow, Azure is enabling log4net and NHibernate is then able to broadcast its logging.

Try adding these blocks to your config and see what effect it has:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
             type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
</configSections>

<log4net debug="false">
    <appender name="WindowsDebugOutput" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender, log4net">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout,log4net">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
        <level value="OFF" />
        <appender-ref ref="WindowsDebugOutput" />
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

You might need to tweak the appender but the key is the `OFF` value in the `logger.level`. You might be able to set this at a higher, global level too. However, my knowledge of how to configure `log4net` is lacking.

Comment: Sorry, @David, that didn't seem to make a difference. Thanks though.